# Swift 2.0 Errors thrown from here are not handled

Tags: swift2

Updating to 2.0 with Xcode 7 Beta 4

I have this code block

```
do
{
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch let err as NSError
{
    println("Dim background error")
}
```

And its giving me the error (on the `try` line)

> Errors thrown from here are not handled.

Is this a compiler error or is there something I am missing in my syntax?

I checked the docs and my code 'looks' correct.

Comment: Replace `println` by `print` and relaunch `xcode`. Maybe the compiler has problems.

Answer (score 17):

What types of errors can `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)` throw?
If it can only throw `NSError`s, then there's no need of specifying this when catching the error. You could simply write:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch {
    print("Dim background error")
}
```

If you want to use the error in your `catch`-scope, you can still access it. Swift automatically binds the thrown error to `error`, which can be used:

```
catch {
    // do something with `error`
}
```

If the method throws multiple types of errors, and you only want to deal with the ones that are `NSError`s, you can conditionally bind them:

```
catch let specialError as NSError {
    // do something with `specialError`
}
```

You must ensure though, that every thrown error is handled. So assuming that the method can also throw a `RandomError` (which I just made up now), you would have to write:

```
catch let randomError as RandomError {
    // do something with `randomError`
}
```

...in addition to the `catch` of the `NSError`.
Or you could of course use the general case:

```
catch {
    // do something with `error`
}
```

---

So I assume your problem can be solved by removing `let err as NSError`, from your `catch`-statement.

Comment: Yea the compiler is broken I think. Autocomplete fails (along with syntax highlighting), and I have tried the generics and and specific it would have thrown (none worked). I should have mentioned in my post. Apologies for the omission.

Comment: Ill post a screen shot next time too, I think it adds weight to a situation like this haha.

Comment: If it helps, add it :)

Comment: XCode 7 Beta 4 works pretty well for me. It seems pretty stable. However, there are a number of language changes from Swift 1 to Swift 2 and the automatic conversion is not always doing the right thing. I'll bet that most of your 200+ errors are due to language changes.

Answer (score 2):

May be a compiler bug. Anyway try removing `let err as NSError` ; `catch` alone is enough if you want to catch all errors.

Also, with Swift 2 you should use `print`, not `println`.

The following code compiles without errors with XCode 7 Beta 4:

```
import AVFoundation

class X {
    func y() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("Dim background error \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried that before posting, didn't work either. I think this beta 4 is way to unstable.

Comment: Did you try exactly this code?. Anyway, I just updated my answers with a code snippet that compiles without problem with XCode 7 Beta 4.

Comment: I think theres issue with my project as a whole. Theres 200+ errors and the syntax highlighting and autocomplete crashes the second I try to type (just like the first release of Swift this is incredibly unstable).

Comment: There might be something wrong in your setup. Did you try a Project>Clean of your project?

Comment: I think I've almost broken my cmd-shift-k keys (i.e. yes)

Comment: Did the 200+ errors happen converting from Swift 1.x toSwift  2? If so, that might be the subject of a new question. I don't think it's appropriate to discuss it here.

Comment: Correct, I chop this up to an unstable beta. It happened to me all the time with Swift 1.0. Looks like 2.0 needs more time in the oven.

Answer (score -1):

check this code that will you get idea on try/catch :

```
    enum ErrorMessages :ErrorType {
    case ErrorDescription
    }

 do
 {
   try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
 } catch ErrorMessages.ErrorDescription
   {
    println("Present the error description here")
  }
```